# Avoid error when running for each loop of range cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the function below. Usually it works fine. But when r is Nothing I get an error message on the line For Each c In r.Cells telling me that "Object variable or With block variable not set".

I don't know exactly why this happens. I imagined that if r was Nothing, the loop just wouldn't run.

```
Function CSVFromRange(r As Range) As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim c As Range

    'Append value and comma
    For Each c In r.Cells
        sTemp = sTemp & "," & c.value
    Next c

    'Remove first comma
    If Len(sTemp) > 0 Then
        sTemp = Right(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 1)
    End If

    CSVFromRange = sTemp
End Function
```

Please tell me an elegant way to make this function not throw an error and also, if you can, educate me on why it is throwing an error.

Comment: It's gonna be along post so bear with me :D

Comment: `Please tell me an elegant way to make this function not throw an error and also, if you can, educate me on why it is throwing an error.` Was my answer too difficult to understand? Or did I miss any question that I should have answered? :)

Comment: Your answer was great!

Comment: If you wish you can accept the other answer. My above comment was not about that. I have no issues about "Accepts" or "Upvotes". :) If I took the `pain` to meticulously answer `all` your questions and that too with examples, then I at least expect an acknowlegement in form of a comment below my answer whether it helped or not? And if it didn't, then what was the problem faced. That's it. I hope that was not too much to ask for? :)

Comment: Sure, not at all :) I appreciate the feedback! I'll try to be more considerate in the future :) I got at least three great answers to this question and upvoted all of them. But I'll start leaving more appreciative comments :) Thank you for helping me out with programming Siddharth!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Why is it throwing an error?**

because it expects a valid range to be passed. See this example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ret

    ret = CSVFromRange(r)

End Sub

Function CSVFromRange(r As Range) As String
    CSVFromRange = r.Value
End Function
```

This is the shortest way to create the error in your case. A range object is passed but it is not initialzed and hence you will get the error. You need to ensure that you pass a valid range. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ret

    Set r = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
    ret = CSVFromRange(r)

End Sub
```

**How can we handle this error?**

You can either handle it in the calling sub or in the function itself. I will show you both

In the Sub

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ret

    If Not r Is Nothing Then ret = CSVFromRange(r)

End Sub

Function CSVFromRange(r As Range) As String
    CSVFromRange = r.Value
End Function
```

In the function

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ret

    ret = CSVFromRange(r)
End Sub

Function CSVFromRange(r As Range) As String
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        CSVFromRange = r.Value
    End If
End Function
```

or

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim ret

    ret = CSVFromRange(r)
End Sub

Function CSVFromRange(r As Range) As String
    On Error GoTo ExitGracefully

    CSVFromRange = r.Value

    Exit Function
ExitGracefully:
    MsgBox Err.Description '<~~ comment this if you do not want any alerts
End Function
```

Comment: SO and all Googler's are very fortunate to have such a valuable asset freely dispersing knowledge.  A heartfelt, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is to test if `r` is `Nothing`

```
Function CSVFromRange(r As Range) As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim c As Range

    If r = Nothing Then
        sTemp = vbNullString  'You can change this to a different default return value
    Else
        'Append value and comma
        For Each c In r.Cells
            sTemp = sTemp & "," & c.value
        Next c

        'Remove first comma
        If Len(sTemp) > 0 Then
            sTemp = Right(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 1)
        End If
    Endif

    CSVFromRange = sTemp
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I use  On Error Goto  you can see the code:

```
Function CSVFromRange(r As Range) As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim c As Range

    On Error GoTo DisplayError
    'Append value and comma
    For Each c In r.Cells
        sTemp = sTemp & "," & c.value
    Next c

    'Remove first comma
    If Len(sTemp) > 0 Then
        sTemp = Right(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 1)
    End If

    CSVFromRange = sTemp
    Exit Function

    DisplayError:
   ... Display a messagebox with error
End Function
```

Comment: You are a lot faster than me :)

Comment: Yeah 7 minutes faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Above answers have answered the specific question you asked. I would also recommend removing the if/end if at the bottom and instead have everything in the For loop. The isempty condition will prevent a double comma when there is an empty cell.

```
Function CSVFromRange(r As Range) As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim c As Range
    'Append value and comma
    For Each c In r.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(c) And c <> r.Cells.Item(1) Then
            sTemp = sTemp & "," & c
        Else
            sTemp = sTemp & c
        End If
    Next c
    CSVFromRange = sTemp
End Function
```